# How can I add a link with a UID from a User Reference from a table in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have the following in Drupal 6:

1. A Master CCK type which contains a User reference field and other fields.  There will only be one record per user here.
2. A View of this CCK, shown as a table, with one of the fields being the user ref from the CCK type.  This field is initially shown as a user name, linking to the user profile.
3. A Second CCK type which can have several pieces of data about a particular user.
4. A View for this CCK type, displaying information as a table.  It takes a user id as an argument (an integer)

I want to click on the user name in the master view, and be directed to the detail view for this user.  To do this, I tried selecting 'Output this field as a link' on the user field.  The thing available for me to replace are:

```
Fields
    * [field_my_user_ref_uid_1] == Content: User (field_my_user_ref)

Arguments
    * %1 == User: Uid
```

However, the [field_my_user_ref_uid_1] element is replaced by the user name, and %1 seems to get replaced with an empty string.  How can I put the user id in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what the right way to do this is, but I'm solving it the hacky way I seem to be solving all my Views problems: by throwing jquery at it.

Currently, the User Ref field already has a link with the user id, so I've added this to the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $rows = $("table.views-table tbody tr");  
        $rows.children("td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
            var $anchor = $(this).children("a");
            var linkElements = $anchor.attr("href").split("/");
            var userId = linkElements[linkElements.length - 1];
            $anchor.attr("href","/my_detail_view/" + userId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hate that I have to do it like this, but I sure do love jquery.